# Laravel: Save to database from multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

How can I save this multidimentional array to may database in laravel?

I have an array `details`. Which has a **key** that has dates. Each date has hours, late, overtime and status.

```
"details": {

      "2019-07-01": {

        "hours": {
          "hours": 3.67,
          "late": 0.33,
          "overtime": 0.83
        },
        "status": "pending"

      },

      "2019-07-02": {

        "hours": {
          "hours": 7.17,
          "late": 0.83,
          "overtime": 2.83
        },

        "status": "approved"

      }

}
```

In my database I have this columns:

**date** , **hours** , **late** , **overtime** , **status**

I want to get the key from `details` and store it to date with its hours, lates, overtime, status.

Result:

```
date         | hours   | late  | overtime   | status
------       | ------  | ------| ------     | ------
2019-07-01   | 3.67    | 0.33  | 0.83       | pending
2019-07-02   | 7.67    | 0.83  | 2.83       | approved
```

How can I store this from laravel to database?

Comment: Can you provide code from your controller what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
foreach($details as $key => $value) {

    DB::table('your_table')->insert(
        [
            'date' => $key, 
            'hours' => $value['hours']['hours'], 
            'late' => $value['hours']['late'],
            'overtime' => $value['hours']['overtime'],
            'status' => $value['status']
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer if it works for you